# Unity VideoPlayer audio broken after an Agora.io video call

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, agora.io

Our application has a scene that does video calling built on agora.io and another scene which plays videos using the Unity VideoPlayer. The problem is that when opening the video player scene after leaving an agora.io call the video playback does not have any audio. This only seems to be a problem on iOS. Android playback is fine.

In xcode when trying play the video we see a lot of the below error repeating while the video plays:

> AudioSampleProvider buffer overflow. 4096 sample frames discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you can provide a stripped-down sample project that reproduces this issue?
Otherwise, my recommendation is try a few things:

1. Do not destroy the Agora engine or disable audio when leaving the Agora scene.
2. Check if the volume of playback is set to zero (with/without #1 above)
3. Call the following private API before joining the agora channel:

   ```
       // Stops the Agora SDK from ending the audio session
   mRtcEngine.SetParameters("{\"che.audio.keep.audiosession\": true}");
   ```